# Would it be possible to have a time series which has zero-mean but is not stationary?

Tags: time-series, nonlinear-regression, stationarity

E.g. $ y_t= A_1y_{t−1} + u_t, u_t ∼ (0, \Sigma_u)$

Would it be possible to let the time series to have zero-mean but is not stationary?

Comment: E.g. mean stays constant, but variance changes over time.

Comment: It seems that in some text book (e.g. http://www.afriheritage.org/TTT/2%20New%20Introduction%20to%20Multiple%20Time%20Series%20Analysis.pdf), "zero-mean" seems to mean that the intercept is 0. I want to be sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. The most famous example is the Random Walk model,

$$y_t = y_{t-1} + u_t, \;\;\; u_t \sim WN(\sigma^2)$$

Since then $y_t = \sum_{i=1}^t u_i$ it follows that

$$E(y_t)=0, \text{Var}(y_t) = t\sigma^2$$

Then $y_t$ is first-order stationary (constant mean), but not second-order (or weakly) stationary.

Comment: Just to make sure, does "zero mean" really mean that the mean is 0 or does it refer to the intercept?

Comment: Zero-mean means expected value equals  zero. And in a time series model it implies that the intercept is zero.